# how to use libssl-dev under cross compiler?

Tags: cross-compiling

I want to cross-compiler this lib for arm target 
http://carnivore.it/2011/04/23/openssl_-_af_alg

but the source code need libssl-dev. I can compile it for i386, because gcc can find the head 
files from libssl-dev, but when I use cross-compiler :arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc, the
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc can't find the head file  ,how can I tell the 
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc where to find the head files ?

Comment: OK, I found the answer. first, download the openssl source , 2nd, use the cross-compiler gcc with -I /openssl/include